How to publish platform event with valid json object inside custom text field?
When I try to assign serialized json string to platform event field and try to publish it, in the platform event payload I get backslash before special character ("")
for example Massage propery value in below payload:
{
   "ReplayId":"value",
   "CreatedDate":"value",
   "CreatedById":"value",
   "EventUuid":"value",
   "Message__c":"{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Case\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/Case/Id\"},\"Id\":\"value\",\"RecordTypeId\":\"value\"}",
   "_ObjectType":"customEvent__e",
   "_EventType":"value"
}

How to get valid json without backslash as Message property value ?
for example:
"Message__c":"{"attributes":{"type":"Case","url":"/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/Case/Id"},"Id":"value","RecordTypeId":"value"}"

Can anyone please help here?
Thanks,
Uday

please provide the Apex Code you are using to create these platform events, so the community can try to verify any mistakes in your logic.

By definition, if you are creating this Platform Event using the REST API. the POST body is JSON
{
   "ReplayId":"value",
   "CreatedDate":"value",
   "CreatedById":"value",
   "EventUuid":"value",
   "Message__c":"someMessage",
   "_ObjectType":"customEvent__e",
   "_EventType":"value"
}

But if someMessage is also JSON, the double quotes in that JSON need to be escaped with \ by the caller
The Salesforce subscriber to the platform event (for example, an Apex trigger), needs to deserialize the value of Message__c into a Case object
Case myCase = (Case) JSON.deserialize(myPlatformEvent.Message__c,Case.class);


You can use Js script and run in console to easily create the json so it can encode it properly, if you are looking to generate it for testing.
